# Struggling with horizontal scrollbar of a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have a DIV element on my page, which whole content is generated by an asyncronous AJAX call. The content are built from P elements (paragraphs) which contains A elements too (href links) and nothing else. In fact my small webpage contains nothing else, but the mentioned DIV which id parameter is "log".

My CSS code for the DIV and the P elements is:

```
<style>

p { line-height:20%;
font-size:9px;
font-family:monospace
} 

a {text-decoration:none} 

a[title]:hover:after {font-size:9px;font-family:monospace}

div#log {
width: 1000px;
overflow-x: scroll;
}

</style>
```

I have no other inline or other style elements on the page at all.

AJAX returned dynamic content looks like as follows:

```
<p>2016-05-17 11:40:23 | <a href="http://example.com/?ip_to_lookup=192.143.125.212">192.143.125.212&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> | Palma de Mallorca - Balearic Islands: Spa... | <a href="http://example.com/?place_to_lookup=Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands" target=_blank>Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands</a> | <a href=# title="Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 6 Build) | OmniAccess Broadband | 0.34776657 sec">Misc data</a></p>
```

The horizontal scrollbar appears, but it looks like disabled, no slider. When the content is wider than 1000 pixel, or I set the width smaller, let's say 500 px, slider still not appears, instead of the content of the paragraphs is warped from the right side to the left side, and overflowing letters cover the beginning of the next line / paragraph.

What to do make the scrollbar work properly?

Comment: Please also add JS and any Fiddles to reproduce the issue.

Comment: not so easy, because how to emulate the AJAX call, and dynamic content?

Comment: You can add any dummy data in `<p>` tag for demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say that your page contains nothing but this `#log` div, I'm going to give an answer that involved changing things slightly, with an explanation to follow:

```css
p {
  /* Added */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /**/
  line-height:20%;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-family: monospace
}

a {
  text-decoration: none
}

a[title]:hover:after {
  font-size: 9px;
  font-family: monospace
}

div#log {
  /* width: 1000px; */
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="log">
  <p>2016-05-17 11:40:23 | <a href="http://example.com/?ip_to_lookup=192.143.125.212">192.143.125.212&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> | Palma de Mallorca - Balearic Islands: Spa... | <a href="http://example.com/?place_to_lookup=Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands"
    target=_blank>Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands</a> | <a href=# title="Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 6 Build) | OmniAccess Broadband | 0.34776657 sec">Misc data</a></p>
  <p>2016-05-17 11:40:23 | <a href="http://example.com/?ip_to_lookup=192.143.125.212">192.143.125.212&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> | Palma de Mallorca - Balearic Islands: Spa... | <a href="http://example.com/?place_to_lookup=Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands"
    target=_blank>Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands</a> | <a href=# title="Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 6 Build) | OmniAccess Broadband | 0.34776657 sec">Misc data</a></p>
  <p>2016-05-17 11:40:23 | <a href="http://example.com/?ip_to_lookup=192.143.125.212">192.143.125.212&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> | Palma de Mallorca - Balearic Islands: Spa... | <a href="http://example.com/?place_to_lookup=Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands"
    target=_blank>Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands</a> | <a href=# title="Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 6 Build) | OmniAccess Broadband | 0.34776657 sec">Misc data</a></p>
</div>
```

If you keep the `width` on `#log`, then the scrollbar will only appear if the `p` tags are wider than 1000px. So, I got rid of it. Then, I added `white-space: nowrap` to `p`, because it seemed like you wanted each entry on one line.

Comment: @Konstantin My pleasure, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding from your question. You need something like this?

```css
p {
font-size:16px;
overflow-x: scroll;
width:100px
}
```

```html
<p>2016-05-17 11:40:23 | <a href="http://example.com/?ip_to_lookup=192.143.125.212">192.143.125.212&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> | Palma de Mallorca - Balearic Islands: Spa... | <a href="http://example.com/?place_to_lookup=Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands" target=_blank>Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands</a> | <a href=# title="Palma+de+Mallorca+-+Balearic+Islands | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 6 Build) | OmniAccess Broadband | 0.34776657 sec">Misc data</a></p>
```

Let me know if I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because of the `line-height` property and width of the `#log` div. Here's your issue replicated:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fze7cw4j/1/)

The issue is the wrapping of the words on to a new line, the `p` element will adapt width of the containing div, and because it exceeds the length it will wrap on to a new line - the line height being the reason it overlaps. Simply add `white-space: nowrap` to your `p` element:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fze7cw4j/2/)